# (2.5D graphics) adding 3tD effects in Raphael.js

Tags: javascript, graphics, raphael

I know that raphael.js doesn't support 3D graphics and whatever 3D effects needs to be kind of faked. I need to generate a tilting effect within my 2D Raphael.js visualization.
I want to tilt a rectangle toward the camera (and having a perspective). My question is how should I write a piece of code to show this tilting? what is the transformation between a streight and tilted rectangle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make tilted rectangle via `Raphael path` **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ry8kT/134/)**

```
var r = new Raphael(10,10, 500, 500);
var p = r.path("M100,300 L120,200 320,200 300,300z");
p.attr({fill: 'yellow', stroke:"red"});
```

Or you can create 3D rectangle like this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ry8kT/136/)**

```
var r = new Raphael(10,10, 500, 500);
var p = r.path("M100,300 L120,200 320,200 300,300z");
p.attr({fill: 'red', stroke:"blue"});
var p1 = p.clone().transform("t10,10").attr({fill: 'yellow'});

var side = r.path("M100,300 L110,310 130,210 120,200z").attr({fill: 'red', stroke:"blue"});
var side1 = side.clone().transform("t200,0");
p1.toFront();
```

If you understood what I did and play with the variables a little in the demos, you can certainly make it look like the way you want.

*Good luck*